# After adding an NSLayoutConstraint, view disappears

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

When I add an NSLayoutConstraint to a view, it results in the view disappearing.

I am using the following code:

```
let test:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
test.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.view.addSubview(test)
test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let topCKCtr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: test.superview, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
topCKCtr.active = true

let topCKCtr1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: test.superview, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
topCKCtr1.active = true


self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

When I debug view hierarchy, i see that the view exists, even though it is not visible. See the below screenshot for details - only the constraint is visible, not the view:
[image]

Comment: Once you start using constraints, you need to define everything.  The frame is no longer used, so add constraints for width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many things that needs to be discussed here.

1. When you use the following

   ```
   test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   ```

   Then it will totally rely on constraints to position and size a view.So you need to set height and width constraints of the view.

   ```
   let topCKCtr2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)

   let topCKCtr3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
   ```

Finally This will be the code which you are looking for

```
            let test:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    test.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(test)
    test.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let topCKCtr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    topCKCtr.active = true
    let topCKCtr1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    topCKCtr1.active = true

    let topCKCtr2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    topCKCtr2.active = true

    let topCKCtr3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: test, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 100)
    topCKCtr3.active = true
```

Comment: You do not have to add the constraints to the view.  Setting the `active` property to `true` activates the constraints and `iOS` takes care of adding them to the proper views.

Comment: You are right though I added the piece of code  I haven't noticed that active part.

Comment: In fact you can activate all the constraints in a single call to `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(_:)`, and the documentation for `NSView.addConstraint(_:)` recommends not using `addConstraint` any more. You'll get more upvotes if you edit your answer to remove the outdated calls.

Comment: Sweet didnt notice that as these days I have been using storyboards to set constraints and haven't followed that. Editing the response based on comments

Comment: Thank you all here,it benefits me a lots!Each one has his good points!^ . ^!@all